# Java PriorityQueue returning the least element as first

Tags: java, data-structures

The javadoc for PriorityQueue in Java says:
The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering.

Does anyone know if this class was intended to be used as heap or just happened to conveniently fit the heap description? 
And if it was supposed to be a heap, then I'm confused as to why they chose to pick 'least' element to be returned by remove() - why would 'least' element have the most priority or be like 'biggest' or 'oldest' element used in heap?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `least element` is an abstract term, like in algebra. It means the first element regarding a specific ordering you define. You can use all kind of things, the biggest element, the most requested element, etc...

Comment: @iralight, I'm glad my comment helped you; I moved it to an answer after doing a little more research, though.

Comment: @UmNyobe, you are right, it is abstract, however, with natural ordering and without customized Comparator, Java gives back a smallest integer or Strings with smallest char value...so that's why I was confused. As Lord Torgamus and Daniel Fischer explained, it's because Priority Queue chose to be a min-heap. The fundamental data structures book I'm reading didn't distinguish between min- and max- heaps, so I wasn't aware. Thanks all again for your input, very helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heaps aren't necessarily supposed to return the biggest element. The heaps that do that are called max-heaps. Java heaps are min-heaps, which are the exact same structure except that they use the greater-than sign instead of the less-than sign in the ordering/comparison step.

After looking through the [source code/documentation for `PriorityQueue`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.java.html) and skimming the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html), I can't see anything that indicates why min was chosen over max. It's possible that it just came down to a coin flip, or that groups of values often go from 1 to n with 1 being the head and least possible value.

Comment: A heap is just an implementation of the priority queue abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

Heaps come in two varieties, max-heaps and min-heaps. The Java PriorityQueue uses min-heaps, so the head/top is the smallest element.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this clarifies it as well

Answer (score 0):

As to why the Least element is returned by remove, from a quick perusal of the documentation, I would assume so that Priority 1 comes before Priority 2

Comment: makes sense, but I was confused as to the definition of priority in this case and what motivated priority 1 to be a smaller integer or first string in alphabet

Answer (score 0):

It is a common misconception that a *priority queue* is a heap. A *priority queue* is an abstract concept like "a list" or "a map"; just as a list can be implemented with a linked list or an array, a *priority queue* can be implemented with a heap or a variety of other methods.